# Integration of external jetty 9 into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I need to edit the `start.ini` file of `jetty` for my `dynamic web project` in `eclipse`. So I am unable to locate it when I installed the `jetty` through the `plugin` available. I have `jetty 9` downloaded on my system and it is absolutely working fine. But I don't know how to integrate the external `jetty` server through `eclipse`. I searched a lot but unable to find the same.

Basically my question is "How to deploy the `dynamic web project` on `jetty server` which is outside the `eclipse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to `Windows->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments`. Then click on `Add`, scroll down to find `Jetty`. Expand the view and select the appropriate version. Just `download and install` or browse to the jetty installation folder till `start.jar`. and click on finish.

Comment: For the above prerequisite is you need to add the `Jetty Adapter Plugin` o the eclipse. Do the following steps. Navigate to `Help->Install New Software`, add the site `http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp/development` to that and click enter. Install the plugin, restart the eclipse and you will be able to do the above procedure described in answer.